# getting twitter api using basic json

Tags: jquery, json, api, twitter

I am fairly new with jQuery and I was trying to get the twitter api using JSON tho I managed to do it with php I wrote this simple piece of code but it does not appear to work

```
(function() 
{
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $.getJSON("https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=TwitterAPI&include_entities=true",function(data)
        {
            var ragzor = data.name;
            $(".ragzor").text(ragzor);
            console.log(ragzor);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: What about adding `&callback=?`: `$.getJSON("https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=TwitterAPI&include_entities=true&callback=?",function(data)`

Comment: hey! thanks alot for your response!! But it still does not appear to work :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jQuery(function($) { // Shorter for $(document).ready(function() {, and you make sure that $ refers to jQuery.
    $.ajax({ // All jQuery ajax calls go throw here. $.getJSON is just a rewrite function for $.ajax
        url: "https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=TwitterAPI&include_entities=true",
        dataType: "jsonp", // dataType set to jsonp (important)
        success: function( resp ) {
            console.log( resp ); // Here resp represents the data reseved from the ajax call.
        }
    });
});
```

---

jQuery source code:

```
$.getJSON = function( url, data, callback ) {
    return jQuery.get( url, data, callback, "json" );
}
```

Redirect you to `$.get`

```
jQuery.each( [ "get", "post" ], function( i, method ) {
    jQuery[ method ] = function( url, data, callback, type ) {
        // shift arguments if data argument was omitted
        if ( jQuery.isFunction( data ) ) {
            type = type || callback;
            callback = data;
            data = undefined;
        }

        return jQuery.ajax({
            type: method,
            url: url,
            data: data,
            success: callback,
            dataType: type
        });
    };
});
```

Ass you can see this returns a initialized version of `$.ajax`

---

So your call rewrites to:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "...",
    dataType: "json" // <- Note json not jsonp,
    success: function() {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: oh wow! thanks for all the explanations i got it now!! thanks :D